# How to initialize a repeated field (Google.Protocol.ProtoBuf) from F#?

Tags: f#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a Google.Protocol.ProtoBuf message defined as:

```
message Rectangle {
     int32 X = 1;
     int32 Y = 2;
     int32 Width = 3;
     int32 Height =4;
 }
 message Word {
    google.protobuf.Int32Value VocabularyId = 1;
    bytes Strokes      = 2;
    string Text        = 3;
    string Confidence  = 4;
    Rectangle BoundingBox =5;
 }

message SaveVocabularyRequest {
    repeated Word Words =1 ;
}
```

In F#, how do I initialize the repeated field "Words" ?
( using: https://github.com/Arshia001/FSharp.GrpcCodeGenerator )

This fails:

```
let h = words |> Seq.map InkWordToWord |> Seq.toList
       
{ Protocol.ProtoBuf.SaveVocabularyRequest.empty() with Words = { Words = {h}}   }
```

Error Message: No Assignment given for field '_UnknownFields' of type 'Protocol.ProtoBuf.SaveVocabularyRequest'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let InkWordToWord (w:Models.InkWord) : Protocol.ProtoBuf.InkWord = 
      let rectangle (dr: Drawing.Rectangle) : Protocol.ProtoBuf.Rectangle =
         {Protocol.ProtoBuf.Rectangle.empty() with X = ValueSome dr.X; Y = ValueSome dr.Y; Width = ValueSome dr.Width; Height = ValueSome dr.Height }
       
      let gg (i:int) : Int32Value =
            let g = Int32Value.empty()
            g.Value <- ValueSome i
            g

      let toBytes (ss:System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection) : byte[] = 
        let ms = new MemoryStream()  
        ss.Save(ms)
        ms.ToArray()
       
          
      { Protocol.ProtoBuf.InkWord.empty() with VocabularyId = match w.VocabularyId with
                                                              | None -> ValueNone
                                                              | Some s -> ValueSome (gg s) ;
                                               Strokes = ValueSome (Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(toBytes w.Strokes));
                                               Text = ValueSome w.Text;
                                               Confidence = ValueSome w.Confidence;
                                               BoundingBox = ValueSome (rectangle w.BoundingBox);
      }

 let SaveVocabularyRequestToGrpc (words:seq<Models.InkWord>) : SaveVocabularyRequest = 
        let v =
             let h = words |> Seq.map InkWordToWord |> Seq.toList
             let r = Protocol.ProtoBuf.Vocabulary.empty()
             // InkWords is a Collection (i.e RepeatedField) in Protobuf.
             r.InkWords.Add(h)
             r
        
        {Protocol.ProtoBuf.SaveVocabularyRequest.empty() with Vocabulary = ValueSome v }
```